# Algorithm to compute DLOG for elliptic curve $E(F_p)$ with order p

Tags: elliptic-curves, discrete-logarithm, group-theory

I was reading about elliptic curves in [this pdf](https://www.math.brown.edu/~jhs/Presentations/WyomingEllipticCurve.pdf). Page 55 of the pdf states that if number of points on elliptic curve #$E(F_p) = p$, then there exists a p-adic logarithmic map that homomorphically maps points in $E(F_p)$ to $F_p$. Now, solving for discrete logarithm on $E(F_p)$ reduces to solving for discrete logarithm in $F_p$.

Can anyone please explain what is p-adic logarithmic map and how to compute it? Does the technique extend to $E(F_{p^k})$?

Comment: For future reference: In SO, cross-posting on two different [sites](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3021935/what-is-p-adic-logarithmic-map-of-an-elliptic-curve-how-to-compute-it) is not a good etiquette. Select one, and give the community a chance to answer.

Comment: Sorry about that. Didn't know where to post. Won't repeat it again.